# Rendered Question

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm using rendered in my visualforce page but I'm not sure if I fully grasp it's behavior.

If I'm using `<apex:outPutPanel rendered="{!test}">`, and test (in my controller) switches from true to false, will the visualforce page immediately hide it? Or will I need to rerender this output panel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to perform a partial page rerender to get the output panel to disappear when the value of `{! test }` changes.

However, it's best to use an outer component as the target of your rerender operations when using a `rendered` attribute. This is because when `rendered` is false, the entire component is never even sent to the client. It's just dropped when the page is rendered by the server, which means that if you tried to rerender it after your condition changed back to `true`, nothing would happen - the component's not there!

It's best to use a structure like this:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="rerenderTarget">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!test}">
        <!-- Stuff goes here -->
    </apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel>
```

Then, your `<apex:commandButton>`s and other components can have `reRender="rerenderTarget"`, and you can be confident that your inner `<apex:outputPanel>` will always be shown or hidden correctly based on the current value of the expression `{! test }`.